# hangups in windows with cygwin not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

hangups in windows not working..

cygwin is also installed

NameError: name 'fcntl' is not defined

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\hangups-script.py", line 9, in <module>
        load_entry_point('hangups==0.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'hangups')()
      File "c:\users\smart\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\hangups\ui\__main__.py", line 988, in main
        }, col_scheme, palette_colors, datetimefmt, notifier
      File "c:\users\smart\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\hangups\ui\__main__.py", line 87, in __init__
        event_loop=urwid.AsyncioEventLoop(loop=loop)
      File "c:\users\smart\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\urwid\main_loop.py", line 111, in __init__
        screen = raw_display.Screen()
      File "c:\users\smart\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\urwid\raw_display.py", line 89, in __init__
        fcntl.fcntl(self._resize_pipe_rd, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
    NameError: name 'fcntl' is not defined
```

Comment: Could you show us some code? (not only error messages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are using (or module you are calling) use `fcntl`.
The incriminated module or line in your code that uses the fcntl module from the standard library will cause an error because this function is available only on Linux.

If you are able to locate the origin of the error, you will solve it either by using another function or module.

Comment: but i installed cygwin

Comment: So you probably installed your module in the windows environment.

Comment: yes 
according to this https://hangups.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Comment: You are supposed to use python for cygwin not for windows, the cygwin version is compiled to use cygwin libraries and support.

Answer (score 1):

As @simonzack [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41694794/403455), you need to use Python for Cygwin.

You may have either installed from a Windows shell, you may not have installed Python for Cygwin, or you may have a Windows Python earlier in your path than the Cygwin one.

Do a `which` or `type` in your shell to determine what the path is to your Python installation that your calling. Make sure it's coming from a Cygwin path not a Windows installation.